# Поменять максимальное и минимальное значение двумерного массива местами

Tags: c++, c

Нужно поменять максимальный и минимальный элемент в двумерном массиве(в данном случае на "участке"). Как это лучше всего сделать? Пробовал свапом и т.д. Буду благодарен за любые советы

```
int n =5, m=5, i, j, min, max, temp;
int v21[n][m];
srand(time(NULL));
printf("Matrix a44( %d, %d): \n",n,m);

for (i = 0;i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        v21[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
        printf("%4d", v21[i][j]);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
min = v21[0][0];
max = v21[0][0];
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    for(i = j;i < m; i++) {

        if(min > v21[i][j]) {
            min = v21[i][j];
        }
        if(max < v21[i][j]) {
            max = v21[i][j];
        }
        //v21[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
cout << "Minimum: " <<min << endl;
cout << "Maximum: " << max << endl;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {    
        if (v21[i][j] == min) {
            swap(max, v21[i][j]);
            temp = min;
        }

        if (v21[i][j] == min) {
            swap(v21[i][j], temp);
        }

    }

}



for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {    
        printf("%4d", v21[i][j]);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: На каком языке программирования? Почему на вопросе стоят сразу два языковых тэга? Набор способов решения этой тривиальной задачи зависят от способа представления двумерного массива с размерами времени выполнения. То что написано у вас - `int v21[n][m];` - в С++ не разрешается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запоминайте не (только) текущие наименьшее и наибольшее значения, а (и) пару индексов для каждого из них.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (min > v21[i][j]) {
      min = v21[i][j];
      iMin = i;
      jMin = j;
    }
    if (max < v21[i][j]) {
      max = v21[i][j];
      iMax = i;
      jMax = j;
    }
  }
}
```

Тогда после двойного цикла:

```
temp = v21[iMin][jMin];
v21[iMin][jMin] = v21[iMax][jMax];
v21[iMax][jMax] = temp;
```

Comment: А что должно быть в циклах поиска минимума и максимума?min = v21[i][j]; v21[iMin][jMin] = min, и соответственно так же в максимуме?